# Java garbage collector does not clean up heap tenured gen space until it reaches 100%

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have Spring Boot micro-services running with Java 17 inside Kubernetes, they have launch parameters: `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx512m`. I see the following unclear case by monitoring Prometheus metrics in Grafana:
**tenured gen space (old generation) continuously linearly grows from 50 to 100% with cycles for 30 hours, then drops back to 50-60% of free space, and repeats the same cyclic behavior again and again.**
This is based on metrics result of `jvm_memory_used_bytes{id="Tenured Gen"}` divided by `jvm_memory_max_bytes{id="Tenured Gen"}`. The same value has metric `jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent` (it equals to a previously mentioned division result). Upon reaching 100%, we have a major GC pause with a duration of 0.4-1.0 second (based on metric `jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max`), and after that rate of tenured space drops.

Tenured max space is 341m (2/3 out of 512m). Other services have similar behavior with differences only in cycle duration, e.g. 5 hours. As GC cleans up tenured space to 50% of free space, I think it means we don't have any memory leaks and objects inside tenured gen are eligible to be cleaned up (unreachable). And looks like nothing suspicious with young gen space, there GC clean up occurs frequently with minor pauses. I think it's a good idea to monitor these metrics and fire alerts by reaching threshold like 90%.

**Questions:**

- Does it somehow indicate that it's not enough max heap size for
  application and I should increase it?
- Should I expect that in an ideally configured application `jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent` will not reach some threshold, e.g. equal to 90%, with more frequent major GC clean ups (and with smaller major GC pauses)?
- Does exist any GC command/hint (`-XX:**`) to
  execute ongoing major clean ups more frequently by reaching some
  threshold?

---

**Update:**
These services are using Serial GC, JVM selected this GC algorithm as a default one based on ergonomics and not G1 GC (thanks a lot to @Stephen to pointing that such behavior not relates to G1 GC). After switching to G1 GC by explicitly specifying JVM option `-XX:+UseG1GC`, behavior is absolutely different and what I expected initially, without any reaching 100% of  tenured gen max space.

Comment: Which GC are you using? Can you try using ZGC? The reason for having generations is to only clean up the old generation rarely and focus on young generations.

Comment: we use a default one, G1 GC. I suppose ZGC should somehow help in that case, but it would be problematic to switch to something new in our case

Comment: If you are using ZGC (which is generally better at doing work while the application is running), you could use the option [`-XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=`](https://malloc.se/blog/zgc-softmaxheapsize) which defines a size the GC tries to stay under but it can be exceeded if necessary. Note that ZGC is not generational in JDK 17. Also, what is important for your application with respect to the GC? Throughput? Latency/Pause times? Something else?

Comment: Aside from that, depending on how fast the old generation grows, you might want to monitor why the old generation grows so much. Do you have many objects that survive enough young collections? You might want to try reducing these (e.g. by reducing the lifetime of these objects in your application or possibly by increasing the young generation size if the young generations are too frequent).

Comment: "what is important for your application with respect to the GC" - I think throughput has more priority. but still, it's unclear for me such G1 GC behavior and looks like not optimal to reach 100%.

Comment: I think it should be quite normal to only do full collections (including the old generation) when the application is (almost) out of memory.

Comment: but it raises probability of OOM occurrences (e.g. in case of spike of traffic), and in that case we are unable to fire alert when we are close to OOM (taking into consideration that it's continuously periodically reaching 100% of heap)

Comment: Did you experience OOMs due to that in your application? I think that the JVM should try to pause the application if necessary.

Comment: nope, we didn't have OOM, but I want to prevent potential OOMs in the future by having such alert

Comment: If a GC get's you back to 50% free, you're far away from an OOM. When the GC doesn't manage to free up (much) memory, that's when you have a problem.

Comment: You might be able to collect old regions earlier using mixed collections by tuning `-XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent`, `-XX:G1HeapWastePercent` and similar options.

Comment: Are you >sure< that you are using G1GC?  This doesn't sound like G1GC behavior.  It actually sounds like the Throughput GC.  Note that the default GC varies depending on your Java version.

Comment: @StephenC thank you a lot for pointing in the right direction, I added `-XX:+PrintGcDetails` and indeed see that we using Serial GC and not G1 GC, JVM selected Serial algorithm as a default one. after switching to G1 GC by `-XX:+UseG1GC`, behavior is absolutely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question based on provided comments and research (thanks to all who were involved in the discussion).

In the described case, JVM automatically selected Serial GC and not G1 GC. G1 GC has absolutely different behavior related to the frequency of tenured space clean up.

Q&A

- Does it somehow indicate that it's not enough max heap size for application and I should increase it?

  - Nope, it does not indicate such issue. In our case, tenured space becomes 50% free after major GC clean up, so we are far away from OOM. Only in case we see a tendency that after each major GC pause, tenured space usage is really close to 100% and duration of GC pauses is increasing with high frequency, it will indicate that we are close to OOM and have issues.
- Should I expect that in an ideally configured application `jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent` will not reach some threshold, e.g. equal to 90%, with more frequent major GC clean ups (and with smaller major GC pauses)?

  - It depends on GC algorithm, each of them has its own behavior.
- Does exist any GC command/hint (`-XX:**`) to execute ongoing major clean ups more frequently by reaching some threshold?

  - JVM GC parameters are specific per GC algorithm. The Serial GC doesn't provide fine-grained control over the tuning parameters compared to more advanced collectors like G1 GC or ZGC.  Serial collector does not have a direct parameter to specify a threshold for cleaning up the tenured generation space more frequently. G1 GC has parameter `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent` which defines the percentage of the entire heap occupancy that triggers garbage collection (default value is 45).

Alternatives to change behavior: switch to G1 GC (JVM option `-XX:+UseG1GC`) or ZGC (`-XX:+UseZGC`).